# Inequality of product of vectors and matrices

Tags: matrices, inequality

Is this true?:
$X^T P sgn(x) \ge 0$ if  the sum of each row of $P$ is 0. X  is a vector, $P$ is a positive definite matrix and sgn(X) is a vextor that each of its elements are the sign of the element in vextor X. 
If not true what is the counter example?

Answer (score 0):

Let
$$
  Q=\begin{bmatrix}-2&3\\1&-1\end{bmatrix}
$$
and
$$
  P=Q^TQ=\begin{bmatrix}5&-7\\-7&10\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Note that $P$ is positive definite since $Q$ is invertible. However, putting $x=\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\end{bmatrix}$ we have
$$
  x^TP\,\mathrm{sgn}(x)=
\begin{bmatrix}2&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}5&-7\\-7&10\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}
  =\begin{bmatrix}2&1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-2\\3\end{bmatrix}
  =-1.
$$